# How to have a constant value for a variable across many html pages using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website with two web pages. In page1 when a button gets clicked it loads page2 and in page2 when a button gets clicked it loads page1.

The problem is i have a variable var c=0 in .js file that increases by 1 when page two loads and doesn't stay 1 when page1 loads rather it becomes 0 again.

**Is there a way by which when var c increases to 1 it stays 1 over all pages till i change it again ?**

Comment: Cookie, localstorage or database.

Comment: There is no persistence in a browser enviroment without actually using persistent storage, such as local storage, cookies, a database or the webserver to store the data.

Comment: Or go old school and encode it in the URL!

Answer (score 1):

Pass the value in url's query string and fetch in other page increase it and set to query string again for next request.

```
page2.jsp?c=0
```

Answer (score 0):

In short: You can't store it as a regular variable if the page is reloading.

You might be able to get away with a single-page app framework like AngularJS, but that's really not worth re-archetecting your codebase for.

Instead, try putting your data in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage).  You can only store strings there, but most things that aren't functions store well with [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

For example:

page1.js

```
var myVar = 'hello';
localStorage.setItem('myVar',myVar);
```

page2.js

```
var myVar = localStorage.getItem('myVar');
console.log(myVar); // Logs 'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the few options available:

- Cookies: Click [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-cookies/)
- Local Storage : [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)
- JSON data: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_native_JSON)
- Or add them into your database/webserver.

It all comes down to you and your project.. 
Good luck with your project!